# Good book on topological group theory?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

I'm looking for a good introduction to the theory of locally compact groups and their representations. It may assume the reader to be familiar with basic group theory, topology and measure theory.

Comment: The title of your question seems to be slightly different from the body of your question. One asks about topological groups and the second one about representation theory of locally compact groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a classical Lev Pontrjagin’s book “Continuous groups” or “Topological groups” (original is in Russian, but [there exists an English translation](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=D50OAAAAQAAJ&redir_esc=y) too). Also I often encountered references to 
“Abstract Harmonic Analysis” by E.Hewitt and K.Ross it this context, but I never saw this book. :-)

Comment: “Abstract Harmonic Analysis” by E.Hewitt and K.Ross is indeed a very nice book. However, IMHO, Folland is better for an introductory reading.

Comment: In your more recent [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/977796/118481) to a similar question you mention a much newer book (2008). Can you comment on the similarity/differences?

Answer (score 3):

You may consider G. B. Folland's book [A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis](http://books.google.ca/books/about/A_course_in_abstract_harmonic_analysis.html?id=0VwYZI1DypUC).