# Reference for Topological Groups

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups

Topological groups were a topic that were covered minimally at my undergraduate institution but it's a topic that I'm finding a need quite a bit in the number theory I'm reading (class field theory).

Is there a recommended source that covers the general theory preferably with lots of examples and exercises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alexander V. Arhangel'skii, Mikhail G. Tkachenko, [“Topological groups and related structures”](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/l001#t=aboutBook), Atlantis Press, Paris; World Sci. Publ., NJ, 2008.

Lev S. Pontrjagin [“Topological groups”](http://books.google.com/books?id=D50OAAAAQAAJ), Gordon and Breach, 1966.

Comment: @User1865345 Thanks for fixing the link.

Comment: Sure. That's what community is meant for - contributing in any way to make a post useful. I already voted your other post of recommendation. Lev S. Pontrjagin's book seems to be accessible for me who is interested in studying invariance problems in statistical inference.